# Try create a walking game

Tags: javascript

I tried to write a game, but I did something wrong, and I don't know what particularly. I have two main problems there:

1) When I try to delete pipe, which leaves borders my canvas (I did it with help `splice(i,1))`, I got an error, when the first pipe leaves. I don't know why and how to fix it.

2) Then more time animation goes, then faster variable `heroY` changes and my hero goes down, but I don't understand why it happens?
Please, help me fix these problems, thanks.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/xctapx/pen/yLLGyjv;

JS Code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let bottom = canvas.height,
    dx = 2,
    randomHeight,
    jumps = 0;

const hero = new Image();
hero.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/SNRYWBZh/man.png";

let heroHeight = 75,
    heroWidth = 100,
    heroX = 40,
    heroY = bottom - heroHeight;

const pipe = new Image();
pipe.src = "https://i.postimg.cc/ZqHJsRRD/pipe.png";

let startPipePos = canvas.width,
    pipeHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90),
    pipeY = bottom - pipeHeight;

let pipes = [{
  x: startPipePos,
  height: pipeHeight,
  pipeY: bottom - pipeHeight
}];

pipe.onload = () => {
  game();
}

function game() {
  action();
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(game);
}

function action() {
  for (let i = 0, len = pipes.length; i < len; i++) {

    pipes[i].x -= dx;

    if (pipes[i].x == 600) {
      randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90);
      pipes.push({
        x: startPipePos,
        height: randomHeight,
        pipeY: bottom - randomHeight
      });
    }

    if (heroY < bottom - heroHeight) {
      heroY += .7;
    }

    // if(pipes[i].x < -30) {
    //     pipes.splice(i, 1);
    // }
    if (heroY >= bottom - heroHeight) jumps = 0;
  }
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(hero, heroX, heroY, heroWidth, heroHeight);
  for (let i = 0, len = pipes.length; i < len; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(pipe, pipes[i].x, pipes[i].pipeY, 30, pipes[i].height);
  }
}

document.onkeypress = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode != 32 || jumps >= 2) return;
  heroY -= 90;
  jumps++;
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="525px" style="background-color: rgba(101, 99, 185, 0.808);"></canvas>
```

Comment: my comment is just recommendation, maybe it helps to save your time, try to practice with canvas/game frameworks (phaser, pixi etc).They help you to understand architecture/good programming style and you will have more results

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: So do you expect us to read the code to reconstruct what the game is about and which controls are available, what the goal is, and when the problem occurs? Sorry, but maybe you should explain *exactly* what the the sequence of events/manipulations is that leads to which behaviour. Like "delete pipe"? No idea what that is about...

Answer (score 0):

1) run your loop in reverse, like this - `for(let i = pipes.length; i > -1; i--)` to avoid array length changes messing up your for loop

2) you'd need to separate your render loop from action loop and use fixed timestep to keep everything in sync